# SQL - Transfer Table(?) unique data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

I'm very green in the area of SQL, so I don't know what the idea or type is really called but I will call em "Transfer tables" and I will try to explain what I mean and my problem. Please correct me!

#### Description

3 tables.

Contacts: ID(primary key), Firstname, Lastname, SSN etc

Address: ID(primary key), City, Street etc

ContactsTransferAddress *(short: CTA)*: ID(primary key), ContactID(foreign key), AddressID(foreign key)

#### The problem

Now this is just an exercise... For now I've made a stored procedure that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddAddress] 
    @Street varchar(MAX),
    @City varchar(MAX),
    @CID int, --ContactID
    @AID int OUTPUT --AddressID
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Addressess(Street,City) VALUES (@Street, @City)
    SET @AID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT INTO CTA(CID,AID) VALUES (@CID, @AID)
END
```

Is there a way to make 2 people share the same AddressID(AID) when putting the connection data in the CTA? Right now, I get that my SP above will give different IDs for each address. But I don't know how to have unique addresses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define the `Addresses` table so duplicates are not allowed:

```
alter table Addresses add constraint unq_Addresses_City_Street
    unique (City, Street);
```

Then you have to do something about duplicates, because your code will fail.

Because you are learning, I'm going to suggest just a check and insert approach:

```
SELECT @AID = AddressId
FROM Addresses
WHERE Street = @Street and City = @City;

IF @Aid IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Addresses(Street, City)
        VALUES (@Street, @City);

    SET @AID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;

INSERT INTO CTA (CID, AID)
    VALUES (@CID, @AID);
```

In more serious code, I would take other precautions.  IN particular:

- I would use transactions and locking to prevent issues in a multi-threaded environment.
- I would use the `OUTPUT` clause to return inserted ids.
- I might use `TRY`/`CATCH` on the `INSERT` rather than `IF` to check if the constraint is violated.

Comment: Damn, when I look at your code it looks so easy! I get what you do, but about your alter procedure. I changed the spellling so it fitted my, with Addresses to Addressess. But "unq_Addresses_Address unique (Address);" - which column is that on? Huge thanks again mate for a very quick answer!

Comment: @Kalle . . . I fixed the answer.